# Datatable with 50k + lines fails me

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am mounting a table and perfect until I want to show more data, I have read that I can use server side but I have not found any example how to consume an web service that returns json

**html**

```
<table id="datatable-buscador" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nº reco.</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Id trabajador</th>
        <th>Trabajador</th>
        <th>Id empresa</th>
        <th>Ref. Int.</th>
        <th>Nombre empresa</th>
        <th>Visado</th>
        <th>Prop.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

**javascript**

```
  let $tabla = jQuery("#datatable-buscador");

  $tabla.dataTable().fnDestroy();

  $tabla.dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[15, 25, 30, -1], [15, 25, 30, "All"]],
    "lengthChange": false,
    "order": [1, "desc"], //columna 0 y ordenar desc
    "language": { "url": "/src_reconocimientos/includes/js/utils/spanish.json" },
    "ajax": {
      url: "/example/example.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: { "tipo": tipo, "dias_reco": diasReco },
      timeout: 180000 //3 min
    },
    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
      jQuery(row).attr("id", data.N_RECONOCIMIENTO);
    },
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        // targets: "_all",
        targets: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8],
        className: 'dt-body-center'
      },
    ],
    "columns": [
      { "data": "N_RECONOCIMIENTO" },// 0
      {
        "data": null,
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
          return formatFecha(data.FECHA_RECONOCIMIENTO);
        }
      }, //1
      { "data": "DNI" }, // 2
      { "data": "NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR" }, // 3
      { "data": "EMPRESA" }, // 4
      { "data": "REF_INTERNA" }, // 5
      { "data": "NOMBRE_CLIENTE" }, // 6
      { "data": "VISADO" }, // 7
      { "data": "PROP" }, // 8
    ]
  });
```

json:

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "N_RECONOCIMIENTO": 29457,
        "FECHA_RECONOCIMIENTO": "2021-10-11",
        "DNI": "28460Q",
        "NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR": "CAMPS",
        "EMPRESA": 112390,
        "REF_INTERNA": "Ref_interna?",
        "NOMBRE_CLIENTE": "example",
        "VISADO": "N",
        "PROP": "Prop?"
    }, {
        "N_RECONOCIMIENTO": 2907,
        "FECHA_RECONOCIMIENTO": "2021-10-14",
        "DNI": "414J",
        "NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR": "CARLOS",
        "EMPRESA": 103482,
        "REF_INTERNA": "Ref_interna?",
        "NOMBRE_CLIENTE": "(ACUERDO DE COLABORA)",
        "VISADO": "N",
        "PROP": "Prop?"
    }, {
        "N_RECONOCIMIENTO": 2619,
        "FECHA_RECONOCIMIENTO": "2021-04-16",
        "DNI": "72306W",
        "NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR": "DIEZ",
        "EMPRESA": 29514,
        "REF_INTERNA": "Ref_interna?",
        "NOMBRE_CLIENTE": "example 365, S.L.",
        "VISADO": "S",
        "PROP": "Prop?"
    }]
 }
```

when pointing to the url of the ajax what it returns me is a json that changes the content according to the data that I pass to it, but when I want to get more 50000 records, the table fails me, so I want to implement serverside, how can I implement it and keep pointing the same url? I don't see anything related in the datatables examples

**add info:**
It is a very simple company webservice that receives data through my php script with cURL, in this it receives a type of request (it can be 1, 2, 3) and receives parameters (variables), the web services does the queries, simple queries and returns the result as json, it cannot be interacted any more, that's why when I try to process 50000 the datatable gives me an error. my question is: how can I do an intermediate step to process so many lines?

Comment: Where your data stored? In DataBase, file, somewhere else? If it stored in DB the simplest PHP script can select data from DB table(s) and return it to JS in JSON format

Comment: They are stored in a database, but I only have access through a web service that returns a json, I always point to the url and it returns the json already mounted, I cannot make a different script with queries

Comment: Are you saying that the API provided by that URL does not allow you to specify paging (or filtering or sorting) parameters in the URL itself? If the URL can only ever return 50,000 records then you cannot use it _directly_ to implement DataTables server-side processing. For DataTables server-side processing to work, DataTables needs to be able to send a request to the server (or, in your case the URL), telling it which page of results to return, (and, optionally, how the data needs to be sorted & filtered).

Comment: It is a very simple company webservice that receives data through my php script with cURL, in this it receives a type of request (it can be 1, 2, 3) and receives parameters (variables), the web services does the queries, simple queries and returns the result as json, it cannot be interacted any more, that's why when I try to process 50000 the datatable gives me an error. my question is: how can I do an intermediate step to process so many lines?